# React Router Ordering

Tags: react-router

I had the router specified as below, and having url http://localhost:8000/billing/bill/linematching/c55718e9-9d70-4b65-88ba-fca97d900ca5/693 is able to land on the TBLineMatchingPage

```
    <Route
        path="/billing/bill/linematching/:billingRunId"
        component={TBCustomersPage}
    />
    <Route
        path="/billing/bill/linematching/:billingRunId/:accountNumber"
        component={TBLineMatchingPage}
    />
```

But after someone did packages upgrade task, the same url cannot be landed to the TBLineMatchingPage anymore, and I have to move that route on top of TBCustomersPage in order for it to work.

```
    <Route
        path="/billing/bill/linematching/:billingRunId/:accountNumber"
        component={TBLineMatchingPage}
    />
    <Route
        path="/billing/bill/linematching/:billingRunId"
        component={TBCustomersPage}
    />
```

Is there a reason why? And what's changed?

Comment: Have you checked the changelog?

Comment: I had a quick read and couldn't find specific relevant info?